# Finding a concrete Doob decomposition

Tags: probability, measure-theory, martingales

> Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_n^2] < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$ for all $n$. Let $M = \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k$. We consider everything relative to the filtration $\mathcal{F}$ generated by the $X_i$ and want to calculate predictable process $\langle M \rangle$ such that $M^2 - \langle M \rangle$ is Martingale.

So the requirement $\mathbb{E}[X_n^2] < \infty$ allows us to use Doob's decomposition theorem, which means that $\Delta \langle M \rangle_n = \mathbb{E}[\Delta(M_n^2) | \mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_n^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] - 2M_{n - 1} \mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal{F}_{n - 1}]$. If we can evaluate this and determine $\langle M \rangle_1$ we know $\langle M \rangle_n$ for all $n$, but I struggle with both of these. We have not used the requirement $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$ yet. The only way I can think of using this, is that this implies that $M$ is martingale. I don't know why that is relevant though. Can we even determine $\langle M \rangle_1$ instead of leaving that arbitrary? The definition of martingales does not require anything of the first element of the stochastic process.

Comment: I think there is an assumption on the $X_n$ missing.- do you assume that they are independent?

Comment: @saz Yes, thank you.

Comment: With independent increments, the "quadratic variation" is a deterministic process, $\langle M \rangle_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \sigma^2_k$ where $\sigma^2_k$ is the variance of $X_k$. (The initial value of $M^2 - \langle M \rangle$ is zero.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $Y=(Y_n)$ is an adapted sequence of integrable random variables, and you seek the Doob decomposition $Y_n = K_n+V_n$ in which $K$ is a martingale and $V$ is predictable. Observe that you would then have $\Bbb E[Y_n\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}] = K_{n-1}+V_n$ for $n= 1,2,\ldots$. Taking differences: $\Bbb E[Y_n\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}]-Y_{n-1} = V_n-V_{n-1}$. Therefore (assuming $V_0=0$)
$$
V_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\Bbb E[Y_k\mid\mathcal F_{k-1}]-Y_{k-1}\right)
$$
for $n=1,2,\ldots$. In the same way,
$$
K_n=Y_0+\sum_{k=1}^n \left(Y_k-\Bbb E[Y_k\mid\mathcal F_{k-1}]\right).
$$

Now you can apply the discussion above to $Y_n=M_n^2$, and your $\langle M\rangle$ would be my $V$.

Comment: Thank you. Pulling the $\langle M \rangle_{n - 1}$ in the expectation we get $\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( \mathbb{E}[X_n^2 \ | \ \mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] + M_{n - 1}\mathbb{E}[2X_n | \mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] \right)$. I think there shoulld be a simplification possible using $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$, but I don't see it. What do you think?